# Object Tag Property equivallent in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

What is the equivalent of Object Tag property http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tag%28v=vs.110%29.aspx in Objective-C ?

I want to attach an object to an NSImageView then retrieve it later so how to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

There's no direct equivalent of Object Tags in Objective-C.

If you want to attach another object you'll need to either:

- subclass `NSImageView` and add a new object property,
- create a category on `NSImageView` and use the **associated objects** runtime feature:

> ```
> - (void)setAssociatedObject:(id)object {
>      objc_setAssociatedObject(self, @selector(associatedObject), object, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
> }
>
> - (id)associatedObject {
>     return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, @selector(associatedObject));
> }
> ```

See Apple's docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html) for more info.